# Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param “state” missing

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, authentication

Hello comunity i got this error. I already tried with the solutions like session_start() in both scripts.

Now fb login is working fine with few accounts like mine and the others developers from the project. But when others clients try to get it it doesn't work

Here's my code. If someone can help me will be great.

Thanks and regards

```
<?php


# Start the session 
    session_start();
# Autoload the required files
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Set the default parameters
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '129284427705486',
  'app_secret' => 'b08b2cb086d211762b7587deafcde564',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
$redirect = 'http://hola.com/sub/facebook/index.php';

# Create the login helper object
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

# Get the access token and catch the exceptions if any
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

# If the 
if (isset($accessToken)) {
      // Logged in!
     // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
      // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] 
      // But we shall we the same page

    // Sets the default fallback access token so 
    // we don't have to pass it to each request
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

    try {
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,name,picture.width(250).height(250)');
      $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $completename = $userNode->getName();
    $iduser = $userNode->getId();
    $username = str_replace(' ', '', $completename);
    $emailuser = $userNode->getProperty('email');
    $pictureuser = $userNode->getPicture();
    $picture = $pictureuser['url'];
    $userlocation = $userNode->getLocation();
    $bdconect = new Mysqli();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $iduser";
    $array = $bdconect->query($query);


    if($array->num_rows == 0){
        $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('".$iduser."','".$username."',NULL,NULL,'".$completename."','".$emailuser."','".$picture."',NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL)";
        $insertuserfb = $bdconect->query($query);
        if($insertuserfb->num_rows == 1){
            setSession($username,$iduser);
        }
        else{
             setSession($username,$iduser);
        }

    }
    else{
         setSession($username,$iduser);
    }

}else{
    $permissions  = ['email'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect,$permissions);
    header("Location: $loginUrl");
}



 function setSession($completename,$iduser){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $completename;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $iduser;
    $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;
            header('Location: webpage');

}
```

Comment: Well have you debugged the session yet? Checked if the session id stays the same, whether the browser accepted the session cookie and properly sends it back, etc. ...?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Can you help me with that solution? I already checked with (!session_id())

Comment: Just wanted to mention that your app secret should be kept secret on your server and should never be posted on a public site like stack overflow. Please reset your app secret immediately